# Will Inna's Mantra work with Crudest Boots?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've found a number over overlaps with items in my current sets and was wondering if they actually work together.

I have [The Crudest Boots](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-crudest-boots) which means that my Mystic Allys is duplicated. I'm using the fire rune for 10% extra damage. Am I right in thinking that the bonus is actually 40% now? 10% per mystic ally and 100% bonus on each ally from [Inna's](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/innas-hold).

Am I also right to assume that if I can find the other bits of Inna's Mantra set that when I use Lashing Tail Kick, each mystic ally will also cast it, so I'll get three casts, including myself.

Comment: I removed my completely incorrect answer. I'm sorry for the misinformation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a 4x bonus. The crudest boots *do* double the passive effect, and Inna's Mantra 2-set bonus does it again (meaning you can get 40% damage from fire, 16 spirit/s from air, etc).

You are also correct to assume that you get one cast per *Mystic Ally*, so for example you would get 3 *Lashing Tail Kicks* (including your own). Each ally casts at the enemy nearest to them (not the one you're aiming for). However, this may not be very strong compared to the other sets (see [this thread](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/17346888099) for a discussion on the topic),

Sources:

[Diablo Wikia - Inna's Mantra](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Inna's_Mantra)

[Gaming SE Chat - user *Chippies*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23487400#23487400)

Comment: For an example of it actually being a 40% damage boost, see [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23487400#23487400)

Comment: @Arperum Thanks. Added that link as a source

Comment: Oh wow, I was used as a source. I'm flattered :P

Comment: @Chippies You did science. You should be proud :)